# Python - Find Coordinates Relative to Screen

Tags: python, image, coordinates, box, bounding-box

Hi I'm not really sure how to phrase this question but basically,

[image: S]

`x1: 575, y1: 76, x2: 1585, y2: 780` is the window position on my screen which is `1920x1080`

The smaller box in the window, `x1: 539, y1: 257, x2: 752, y2: 498` is relative to the window which is the above coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the `x1, y1, x2, y2` of the smaller box relative to my screen `1920x1080`.

It's more of a maths problem and i'm completely lost on how to do this haha e_e

Expected answer is : `x1: 1120, y1: 337, x2: 1333, y2: 574` +- a bit of offset because all of the above values and this expected values are measured in paint on my PC haha e_e

Please help any of you maths wiz out there! :(

Comment: What calculations have you tried already ?

Comment: HAHAH @DeanVanGreunen yeah i'm sort of dumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a math problem, youre correct.

```
absolutex1 = outerx1 + innerx1
absolutey1 = outery1 + innery1
absolutex2 = outerx1 + innerx2
absolutey2 = outery1 + innery2
```

When looking at the inner, it is relative to the Outer x1,y1 only.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked! haha can't believe i was so stupid

Comment: we get hiccups sometimes.  Its ok.